# JPA/Hibernate inheritance while loading: IllegalArgumentException, try to set wrong subclass

Tags: jpa, jpa-2.0, java-ee-6, jboss6.x

I'm using JBoss 6.1, I have the a JPA entagled situation, as a result I got the following error message:

IllegalArgumentException: Can not set EquipmentB field EquipmentCycleB.equipment to EquipmentA

suppose that each entity has an @Id annotated field:

A first hierarchy

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DIS", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 1)
public abstract class Equipment { ... }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class EquipmentA extends Equipment { ... }

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class EquipmentB extends Equipment { ... }
```

A second hierarchy

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name = "DIS", discriminatorType = DiscriminatorType.STRING, length = 10)
public abstract class EquipmentCycle { 

   ...

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("A")
public class EquipmentCycleA extends EquipmentCycle {

   @JoinColumn(name = "EQUIPMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
   @ManyToOne
   private EquipmentA equipment;

   ...

}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("B")
public class EquipmentCycleB extends EquipmentCycle { 

   @JoinColumn(name = "EQUIPMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
   @ManyToOne
   private EquipmentB equipment;

   ...

}
```

So far nothing strange, go on, the class say Status

```
@Entity
public class State {

   @JoinColumn(name = "ENTITY_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID", nullable = false)
   @ManyToOne
   private EnityWithState enityWithState;

   @JoinColumn(name = "EQUIPMENT_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
   @ManyToOne
   private Equipment equipment;

   @JoinColumn(name = "EQUIPMENT_CYCLE_ID", referencedColumnName = "ID")
   @ManyToOne
   private EquipmentCycle equipmentCycle;

   ...

}
```

and the class which the state belong to

```
public class EnityWithState { 

...

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "enityWithState", fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL,   orphanRemoval = true)  
    private List<State> stateHistory;

    ...

}
```

Don't ask me why, I have just found it.
After some time the DB store the following data

```
Table Equipment

ID  DIS
--------------------------------
1   A  ...
2   B  ...

Table EquipmentCycle

ID  DIS  EQUIPMENT_ID
--------------------------------
 1   A    1
 2   B    2

Table State

ID  ENTITY_ID EQUIPMENT_ID EQUIPMENT_CYCLE_ID
---------------------------------------------
1     1           1              1
2     1           2              2
```

And finally, when I try lo load the EnityWithState with id 1, I got the following error:

IllegalArgumentException: Can not set EquipmentB field EquipmentCycleB.equipment to EquipmentA

Does anyone have any idea? I googled but I found nothing.
Could it be an Hibernate/JPA bug?

Thanks in advance for the help